# Increasing the length of the rectangle in smartdiagram

Tags: smartdiagram

I am looking for a setting to increase the length of the rectangle produced using the `smartdiagram` for a descriptive diagram. It seems that most of the horizontal space is not utilized.

[image]

below is the code to reproduce this:

```
\usepackage{smartdiagram}
\smartdiagramset{uniform color list=grey for 3 items}
\smartdiagram[descriptive diagram]{
{Step 1,{UTF-8 and BOM encoding} to all (.csv) files before merging},
{Step 2,{Replace \&  Merge 'NA' values of \textbf{title} column} to 'comments'},
{Step 3,{Filter and Merge topics that have atleast received a comment}}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use `description width` and `description text width` arguments to `\smartdiagramset`.

I also fixed a few issues with the code to make it compile.

Here is an MWE:

```
\documentclass{report}

\usepackage{smartdiagram}

\begin{document}
    
    \smartdiagramset{
        uniform color list=gray for 3 items,
        description width=12cm, % <-- width of a drawn bounding box
        description text width=11cm % <-- width of a text within that box
    }
    \smartdiagram[descriptive diagram]{
        {Step 1, {UTF-8 and BOM encoding to all (.csv) files before merging}},
        {Step 2, {Replace \&  Merge 'NA' values of \textbf{title} column to 'comments'}},
        {Step 3, {Filter and Merge topics that have at least received a comment}},
    }

\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Thank you so much!